# Values not passing from TextBox to Servlet File

Tags: java, servlets

I am filling the simple  HTML form with user entering name and age value & by hitting submit button he goes to next servlet file.

My html code is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="display" method="post">
        Name <input type="text" value="name"> <br> </br>
        Age <input type="text" value="age" > <br> </br>
       <input type="Submit" value="Submit" >
    </form>
</body>
```

Servlet coding is

```
package pack;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class display extends HttpServlet {


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
    String n = request.getParameter("name");
    String c = request.getParameter("age");


    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>Servlet display</title>");            
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    //out.println("<h1>Servlet display at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
    out.println("I am "+n+" and my age is "+c);
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
    }
 }
```

I should be getting output as :

I am (some name as entered in textbox) and age (some age as entered in textbox).

But output is:

I am null and my age is null.

Values are not passed from textbox to servlet file.
Can somebody suggest what is wrong in code...??

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, replace the `value` attribute by the `name` attribute, e.g.:

```
<input type="text" name="name">
```

The `value` attribute also exists but it is used to set an initial value inside the textbox.

Comment: Thanks @David ..i am getting the correct result on replacing the value attribute by name attribute in both textbox. Can you please elaborate why so ?

Comment: When you call `request.getParameter("name")` in your servlet, you are referring to the `name` attribute of the textbox. The `value` attribute is just used to set an initial (default) value.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed **name** attribute in input tag.
Add these in your form:

```
 <form action="display" method="post">
    Name <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="name"> <br> </br>
    Age <input type="text" name="age" id="age" value="age" > <br> </br>
   <input type="Submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

You will get Output as I am **name** and my age is **age**

Answer (score 0):

**You need to change value to name or add name="name" attribute**, because "The value attribute specifies the value of an  element." and "the name attribute specifies the name of an  element."